# How xtaskcreat creates task without function body in FREERTOS

Tags: c, rtos, freertos

I am new to RTOS and I was going through some demo code in freeRTOS, I came across xtaskcreate function.I know that when a function is called it should have its function body some where in the code.When I referred the the task.c file and did not found any xtaskcreate function body. So can some one explain me where the xtaskcreat function body is present else if not then how it is executed.

Comment: It can be macro to another function.

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in file `Source/tasks.c` near line 595 (FreeRTOS v9.0.0rc2).

But if `SUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCACTION` is not defined, `xTaskCreate` won't be defined too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which FreeRTOS version you are using.

The latest V9.0.0rc2 has both xTaskCreate() and xTaskCreateStatic() as separate functions in tasks.c.  Some versions will have both calls defined as macros that each calls xTaskGenericCreate() with parameters set appropriately for the required behavior (hiding the complexity from the end user).

In both cases its easy to find out.  The 'Task' [on the front of the function name tells you the prototype is in tasks.h](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide.html) - so just search that file for xTaskCreate() and see if it is a direct function call or a macro that calls another function - which you can then find in tasks.c.